# Executing Python Script and C# Script Parallely on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio

This is a common question that most people asked already. I go through the lot of documentation that written on different topics how to integrate Python and C#. But most of them are too difficult and can not apply with my requirements.

I have a main program that written on Visual Studio and C#. Also I have another program written in normal Python. I want to run that python script parallely with the C# program. Can anyone tell me how can I perform this task.

Comment: what is your intention? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to run the Python script after some C# script.

Comment: You may execute the python script at the end of your c# script?
`Process.Start(...)`. 
If you can describe your problem more precisely, it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling Python from [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) in Visual Studio, you can use it to call Python's native functions, classes, types, methods and it'll compile directly to bytecode. Also, since you have your native functions supported, you will be able to import modules and dependencies as well.

Also, there is

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "python script.py");
```

Where script.py is your python script and it'll get executed from the cmd, the main difference is that IronPython will compile directly inside your C# script and the second method will run cmd where you'll need to have Python locally installed in order to run the script you're calling.

Comment: If he just wants to execute two separate scripts, IronPython seems to be a bit too much.

Comment: I just assumed he had already tried `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "python ./script.py");` and he wanted to write both scripts in the same file.

Comment: Yes I want to write both scripts in same C# file

Comment: I editted my answer for you, @ChathurikaJayawardana . The first part tells you how to write both scripts in the same file, the second one is a simpler way to execute both files parallely.